# Android: AWS Cognito in combination with API Gateway using wrong credentials

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use AWS Cognito user pools in combination with the AWS API Gateway.

Logging in works fine, when entering the credentials the success handler is called and I can see the credentials. When verifying the JWT token at jwt.io I can also see that the user is correct.

However, when calling the API Gateway using the ApiClientFactory I always receive an error: `com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException: Basic (classic) flow is not supported with RoleMappings, please use enhanced flow. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 1a61f1fd-91d8-11e8-82bc-675071b1c307) (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)`

Please see my code below:

Main activity:

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this) {
            // Obtain the reference to the AWSCredentialsProvider and AWSConfiguration objects
            // Use IdentityManager#getUserID to fetch the identity id.
            IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().getUserID(object : IdentityHandler {
                override fun onIdentityId(identityId: String) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Identity ID = " + identityId)
                }

                override fun handleError(exception: Exception) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Error in retrieving the identity" + exception)
                }
            })
        }.execute()
```

LoginFragment:

```
val authenticationHandler = object : AuthenticationHandler {
    override fun getAuthenticationDetails(continuation: AuthenticationContinuation, userID: String) {
        val authDetails = AuthenticationDetails(inputUsername.text.toString(), inputPassword.text.toString(), null)
        // Now allow the authentication to continue
        continuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authDetails)
        continuation.continueTask()
    }
    override fun onSuccess(userSession: CognitoUserSession, newDevice: CognitoDevice?) {
        progressLoader.visibility = View.GONE
        (activity as? OnboardingActivity)?.proceedAfterLogin()
    }
    override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {
        progressLoader.visibility = View.GONE
        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.ERR_GENERAL, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        snackbar.show()
        progressLoader.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    override fun getMFACode(continuation: MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation) {
        continuation.continueTask()
    }
    override fun authenticationChallenge(continuation: ChallengeContinuation) {
        continuation.continueTask()
    }
}

loginButton.setOnClickListener {
    val userPool = CognitoUserPool(context, AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration)
    val user = userPool.getUser(inputUsername.text.toString())
    progressLoader.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler)
}
```

Api client:

```
val factory = ApiClientFactory().credentialsProvider(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().credentialsProvider)
        val = factory.build(MyClient::class.java)
        try {
            val request = GetChallengesRequest("", nextPageKey)
            val response = client.getRunningChallenges(request)
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            // This catch is allways called with the error
        }
```

The config is loaded using the `awsconfiguration.json` which is stored in the raw resource folder.

When setting a breakpoint in `AWS4Signer` sign method I can see the sign method is called with `AnonymousAWSCredentials` but I really can't figure out why, as I call the method after logging in.

I hope someone can help me resolve this weird issue, it's been bugging me for days!